# How to merge three.js meshes into one Mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible in Three.js to merge two or more meshes, with different materials?

The solutions I've found, merges geometry only, or just puts the Meshes into one  `Object3D` or `Group`.

Comment: Best way to get help is to post code you have so far.

Comment: @gaitat is correct. The renderer just splits the mesh apart again to render it. three.js r.71

Comment: Then why is the rendering much faster, if I merge everything in the 3D editor, before exporting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>Yes:</s> Kind-of (see the comments attached to the question and this answer post):

```
var blueMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x0000FF } );
var redMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color:0xFF0000 });
var meshFaceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [ blueMaterial, redMaterial ] );

var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );

for ( var face in boxGeometry.faces ) {
    boxGeometry.faces[ face ].materialIndex = 0;
}

var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 16, 16 );
sphereGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 5, 0) );

var mergeGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
mergeGeometry.merge( boxGeometry, boxGeometry.matrix );
mergeGeometry.merge( sphereGeometry, sphereGeometry.matrix, 1 );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( mergeGeometry, meshFaceMaterial );
scene.add( mesh );
```

I went with a cube and a sphere because a box for example wants to know a material id for each of its faces.

http://jsfiddle.net/v49ntxfo/

Comment: Falk Thiele answer is good but from my point of view the initial answer would be 'No:'. The merge is applied to the different geometries and materials one by one, but never for the whole mesh together. So, is **NOT** possible to merge different meshes but as many geometries with its material.

Comment: I only see one `Mesh`, where's the merging?  
The only problem with `Group` is that it can't be dragged by `DragControls`.